# Play framework get Response status code in filter

Tags: scala, filter, playframework

I have a filter where-in I do some logging of all the incoming requests such as the request method, path and so on. I would not want to get access to the response headers and I would like to have it as a continuation of what I did to log the incoming messages. Here it is:

```
  def apply(next: (RequestHeader) => Future[SimpleResult])(rh: RequestHeader): Future[SimpleResult] = {
    val result = next(rh)
    if (!rh.path.startsWith("/assets"))
          Logger.info(s"host: ${rh.remoteAddress} ${rh.method} ${rh.path} ${rh.rawQueryString} ${rh.headers.get("user-agent").getOrElse("No user-agent specified")}")
    result
  }
```

I want to also log the response status code at the same line where I log the rest of the parameters. Any ideas how could I do that? Alternatively, I could also get all these values from the result which would mean that I have to do it in the onComplete event. Is that the way to go or any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't you want to access the response headers? There wouldn't be another way to get the response code. I'd prefer to `map` the result.

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext

def apply(next: (RequestHeader) => Future[SimpleResult])(rh: RequestHeader): Future[SimpleResult] = {

    next(rh).map{ response =>
        // This is executed only when the `Future` has been completed successfully.
        if (!rh.path.startsWith("/assets"))
            Logger.info(s"response code: ${response.header.status} host: ${rh.remoteAddress} ${rh.method} ${rh.path} ${rh.rawQueryString} ${rh.headers.get("user-agent").getOrElse("No user-agent specified")}")

        response
    }

}
```

It seems the only thing `map` would miss vs `onComplete` would be when an exception is thrown. Of course, this ought to trigger `Logger.error` anyway. Assuming you'd want to log everything, then `onComplete` would have to do here.

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import scala.util.{Success, Failure}

def apply(next: (RequestHeader) => Future[SimpleResult])(rh: RequestHeader): Future[SimpleResult] = {
    val result: Future[SimpleResult] = next(rh)

    result.onComplete{
        case Success(response) => Logger.info(...)
        case Failure(_) => Logger.info(...)
    }

    result
}
```

The `Failure` case would have no response, but would be 500 - Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the response code from the future `result`, when your `apply` method is running the response code hasn't been determined yet, so you don't really have a choice. The code can be simple though:

```
def apply(next: (RequestHeader) => Future[SimpleResult])(rh: RequestHeader): Future[SimpleResult] = {
  val result = next(rh)
  if (!rh.path.startsWith("/assets"))
    result.foreach { result =>
      val status = result.header.status
      Logger.info(s"host: ${rh.remoteAddress} ${rh.method} ${rh.path} ${rh.rawQueryString} ${rh.headers.get("user-agent").getOrElse("No user-agent specified")} status: $status")
    }
  result
}
```